# Write Double value in numeric cell with specific format in Apache Poi 3.7

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to write a Double value in a numeric cell using a specific format, i mean, the generated xls must have numeric cells containing Double values like, for example: 8,1. I am trying something like:

```java
DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
dFormat.format(doubleValue);
```

But, since format method returns a String, no matter whether I create cells as numeric or not, they always behave as text cells. I was thinking about two options:

- Forcing cells to behave as numeric cells.
- Forgetting about DecimalFormat and use Double class specifying comma as the decimal separator, what i'm not sure it's possible.

Any idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I may be missing something, but I think you just want to style the cell with a format rule to display a single decimal place

```
// Do this only once per file
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(
    wb.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("#.#"));

// Create the cell
Cell c = row.createCell(2);
c.setCellValue(8.1);
c.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

That will create a formatting rule, create a cell, set the cell to be the value 8.1, then style it

Comment: Upvote for friendly environment and it does help me finish my work and made my day!

Answer (score 8):

I tried this working fine...

```
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
HSSFDataFormat hssfDataFormat = wb.createDataFormat(); 
String cellVal = "2500";
cellStyle.setDataFormat(hssfDataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.000"));
newCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
newCell.setCellValue(new Double(cellVal));
newCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

The output is a numeric value with desired format: 2,500.000

Comment: suppose i want to set decimal by using parameter for exmp. in cellStyle.setDataFormat(hssfDataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.000")); in that instead of "#,##0.000" , 4 or 5 decimal which is int or long ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to put both values in one cell? Can you split them up into 2 columns? Excel has a built-in "Texts to Columns" function that you should be able to reference that will split an entire column of text strings into multiple columns based on a delimiter (like a comma). In VBA, it looks something like this:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

As for your first proposed solution, it is not possible to force Excel to treat something as a number if it is not convertable to a number.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @carmalize. I may have explained myself badly, but i don't have "both values", is only one Double value using a comma as the decimal separator.