# Always show two decimal points in excel cells using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-2007

For example,

```
XSSFCellStyle style=(XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("#.##"));

productCell.setCellValue(12.4);
productCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
productCell.setCellStyle(style);
```

This displays `12.4` in the specified cell. It should be `12.40`. The value `12` is displayed as `12.` which is quite unnecessary.

If the value is `0` then, it displays a dot `.`. It should always display two decimal digits - `0.00`, in this case regardless of the value being stored in a cell.

How to force excel to always show two decimal digits in a numeric cell?

---

I use one of the following styles to display numeric cells.

```
XSSFColor commonColor = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
XSSFColor cellBorderColour = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 76, 153));

Font font = workbook.createFont();
font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
font.setColor(IndexedColors.DARK_BLUE.index);

XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(commonColor);
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
style.setFont(font);

style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.HAIR);
style.setBorderColor(XSSFCellBorder.BorderSide.LEFT, cellBorderColour);
style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.HAIR);
style.setBorderColor(XSSFCellBorder.BorderSide.TOP, cellBorderColour);
style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.HAIR);
style.setBorderColor(XSSFCellBorder.BorderSide.RIGHT, cellBorderColour);
style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOUBLE);
style.setBottomBorderColor(cellBorderColour);
```

I applied some excel formulae to perform some calculations on numeric cells that are expected to be performed after applying a number format (rounding half up) on numeric cells.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789627/write-double-value-in-numeric-cell-with-specific-format-in-apache-poi-3-7?

Comment: Yes that behaves exactly the same as mentioned in the question.

Comment: What cell style do you need to use if you're formatting the cell in Excel, to get it to look how you want it to?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Excel formatting, a `#` means "place a digit here only if needed", but a `0` means "always place a digit here, even if it's an unnecessary 0".  You can specify [the data format in Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats) exactly [as you would in Excel itself](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx).  If you want the `0` digits to show up, then you need to use `0`s as formatting digits.  Try

```
style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));
```

This will make the value `0` show up as `0.00` and `12.4` as `12.40`.

Comment: Please also let us know how to get 3 decimals.

Comment: `style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.000"));`

Comment: However, if you use 0.###, integers are formatted with a dot ad the end. For example, 33 is displayed as 33. If you use #.###, 0 is not displayed at all.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

1. Set Cell Style

   ```
   private CellStyle formatDecimalStyle(Workbook workbook, CreationHelper createHelper) {  
       CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
       style.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));
       return style;   
   }
   ```
2. Apply Style on Cell

   ```
   CellStyle style = formatDecimalStyle(workbook, createHelper);
   Cell creditAmountCell = row.createCell(3);
   creditAmountCell.setCellValue(amount);
   creditAmountCell.setCellStyle(style);
   ```