# Comma convert to dot after reading xls file with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a problem with reading xls file by Apache POI.

test.xls contains a cell with general type: 123,56.

Test Code:

```
FileInputStream myxls = new FileInputStream(path);
HSSF myworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);
HSSF mysheet = myworkbook.getSheetAt(0);
HSSF myrow = mysheet.getRow(1);
HSSF mycell = myrow.getCell(0);
System.out.Println(mycell.toString());
```

output: 123.56. The comma converted to dot, but i want to get result as 123,56

I tried to use different methods:

```
mycell.getNumericCellValue(); returns 123.56
mycell.toString(); returns 123.56
mycell.getRichStringCellValue(); returns an exception
mycell.getStringCellValue(); returns an exception
```

I tried to use it:

```
static DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

static String getStringValue(Cell cell) {
    return dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
}
```

but result the same: 123.56

Comment: If cell is 'general' type, then for sure you should use "mycell.getStringCellValue()" and this returns '123,56'.

Answer (score 2):

The value is held as number, and toString conversions in java follow the programmer's notation with a dot.

```
Locale locale = new Locale(...);
String repr = String.format(locale, "%.2f", mycell.getNumericCellValue());
```

Fancy with [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)):

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
String repr = format.format(mycell.getNumericCellValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it just for output, than try this:

```
mycell.toString().replace(".",",")
```

Or you can set specific style for your cell:
[Write Double value in numeric cell with specific format in Apache Poi 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789627/write-double-value-in-numeric-cell-with-specific-format-in-apache-poi-3-7)